# Keyboard shortcut to move tabs around in Firefox on a Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, firefox

The equivalent of it in Windows would be `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `PgUp` / `PgDn`. To reiterate, I am trying to move a tab's position forward and back within the windows via keyboard shortcut using Firefox v82 on macOS 10.15.7.

Can FireFox cycle tabs like it does in Windows 10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no PgUp and PgDn on Mac keyboard but you can get them with fn+↑ and fn+↓ respectively.

So proper combo for moving is ⌃+⇧+fn+↑ (or in another direction last key should be ↓)

It's actually easier than it looks because first three keys are in left corner next to each other.

Comment: BTW, extended keyboards have page up/down/home/end, only laptops don't.